# Steam downloads more and more shader caches at every restart

Tags: games, steam, downloads

I have been using ubuntu steam for a while now. I have pretty big games installed, and so i have activated the shaders pre-caching.
However, at every single start of steam, it will:
-Dowload brand new caches for every game, adding 2gb to the hard drive
-Recompiling everything (apparition of fossilize-replay processes that take up 80% of my processor

I don't think this is normal, as my shader caches folder is now 18gb and keeps growing. Deactivating shaders pre-cache stops the download and recompiling, but doesn't delete the old shaders.
Does anyone know where this problem is coming from?
Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a common complaint about steam I've seen on many websites. Have you tried uninstalling games you no longer play? You can also delete the cache folder (at worst it will cause stuttering but will not break your games) and let it redownload

Comment: Deleting the shaderscache folder does not diminish the "official" amount of shaders detected by steam. It's still 19go now